# Auto Backup database to phone memory and external memory

Tags: android, eclipse

I have back up database function. Can any one help me to write auto back up database function. For every one minute database should be back up to Phone Memory or External Memory.

```
public void backupData() {

    // date
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
    String dbDate = df.format(c.getTime());

    path = dir.getAbsolutePath();
    String currentDBPath = DatabaseHandler.DATABASE_NAME;
    String backupDBPath = "247drcare_" + dbDate + ".db";
    File currentDB = new File(getDBPath(), currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(path, backupDBPath);
    if (currentDB.exists()) {
        FileChannel src;
        try {
            src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();

            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();

            // hide other option
            if (path == "/storage/sdcard0/247DoctorCare") {
                System.out.println(backupDBPath);
                System.out.println(settingSuccess);
                settingSuccess
                        .setText("Backup is successfull to your Phone Memory. Backup file Name : "
                                + backupDBPath);

            } else if (path == "/storage/sdcard1/247DoctorCare") {
                settingSuccess
                        .setText("Backup is successfull to your External Memory. Backup file Name : "
                                + backupDBPath);

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error in retriving current 247DoctorCare Database.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one answered yet!. I used Broadcast Receiver, still i didn't got answer.

Comment: I want to call backupData() function inside Alaram Manager. Please help me how to call this function.